# Why only the left speakers are working?

Tags: windows-7, speakers

I've just bought a 5.1 speakers and only the left side speakers and the center are working. If I plug in the speakers to my mp3 player than each speaker is working, so the speakers are good. I have windows 7 and I can't configure it. Please help me!

I'm sure that the problem is with some settings at the computer. A while ago I had the same issue with some stereo speakers and I can't remember how I've fixed it, but it was only a setting error. I don`t think that my sound card could be the problem, because it's in-built and I have a new motherboard: asus m2n68-am. I've just tested my computer with some stereo head speakers and also only the left one was working. If I start the speakers very loud than the right speakers are making some noise, too

I've connected the speakers with a two channels cable. This is the speakers type: genius sw-hf 5.1 5050 v2

Comment: I would guess that the cable that connects the sound subsystem to the case ports is installed incorrectly.

Answer (score 1):

Check if 3.5 jack is all the way in.
Also there is a possiblity that you have 'mono' selected in sound settings.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your balance might be off.

Open the Sound applet from the Control Panel and click the Configure button for your default sound device. Then go to the Levels tab and click on the Balance button. Adjust the sliders so that the balance is even on both the left and right speakers.

Here's a good link with screenshots: http://www.windows7hacker.com/index.php/2010/02/how-to-adjust-audio-balance-in-windows-7/

Comment: I`we tried it, but even if I balance it all to the right speakers only the noise is louder....

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue with headset. Everything was working fine for more than 2 years, and today,  when I plug headset into jack, only sound was on left side. So, what I do, is that I used Cotton swab to clean that jack. Now I have sound on both headset.

Answer (score 0):

My problem was fixed as soon as I opened the `Control Box` (Alt+G or right click on/in the main window and select it), clicked on the `Audio` (Sound) tab (the second one, from the left) and clicked on the `Reset` button.

In my case, the problem appears to have originated around the time the instalation of some codecs happened.